How to connect raspi4 to blynk apps
Can someone help i am using rpi4 as a microcontroller, the dht22 sends a temperature and humidity data to the rpi4b but it does not connect to blynk cloud I already check the auth token and v0 and v1 digital pins in the web dashboard and it aligned with my code 0,1 am I missing something? The app is offline but it reads.
To answer my questions, on how i can send the data into the blynk cloud.
This is the code I use:
import adafruit_dht
import board
import blynklib
import time

BLYNK_AUTH = 'remove for this post'  # Replace with your actual Blynk Auth Token
blynk = blynklib.Blynk(BLYNK_AUTH)

# Attempt to connect to Blynk server
def connect_to_blynk():
    global blynk
    try:
        blynk.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to Blynk server: {e}")
        time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before retrying
        connect_to_blynk()

dht_device = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D5)  # DHT22 connected to GPIO5

def read_sensor_data():
    try:
        # Read temperature and humidity
        temperature = dht_device.temperature
        humidity = dht_device.humidity
        if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
            print(f'Temp={temperature:0.1f}*C  Humidity={humidity:0.1f}%')
            try:
                blynk.virtual_write(0, temperature)
                blynk.virtual_write(1, humidity)
            except AttributeError:
                print("Lost connection to Blynk server. Reconnecting...")
                connect_to_blynk()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to write to Blynk: {e}")
        else:
            print('Failed to get reading from the sensor')
    except RuntimeError as error:
        print(error.args[0])

# Ensure initial connection to Blynk
connect_to_blynk()

while True:
    read_sensor_data()
    if blynk.connected():
        blynk.run()
    else:
        connect_to_blynk()
    time.sleep(10)  # Delay between readings


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
